# Gdata authorization errors

Tags: python-2.7, gdata

I have installed the google data python library in order to connect to google docs through python. The problem is that I am constantly getting a 401 error, while running the ./samples/docs/docs_example.py (as suggested on https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/python_client_lib?csw=1#library) saying that authorization is required. But this is really strange, because I ran the tests using ./tests/run_data_tests.py and everything seemed to be fine (no errors here). Also I put in the right credentials of my google account, while running docs_example.py.

Has someone came across this issue before, or does somebody know a solution??

Tnx for your help.